# passing variables as string parameters to gaq.push

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, google-analytics

I am adding a Google Analytics tracking event to nav menu links, with this code:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {
        $("body").on('click', '.menu-item a', function () {
            var trackingCode = $(this).next(".ga-tracking");
            if (trackingCode.length > 0) {
                var t1 = trackingCode.data("tracking-1"),
                    t2 = trackingCode.data("tracking-2"),
                    t3 = trackingCode.data("tracking-3"),
                    t4 = trackingCode.data("tracking-4"),
                    params = "'" + t1 + "','" + t2 + "','" + t3 + "'";
                _gaq.push([params]);
            }

        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

you can see it working here: http://paulwp.com/blog/
to trigger the code, click on the Blog link in the top black bar.

This is the error I get:

```
_gaq.push processing "'_trackEvent','Store_Outbound','Link_Click'" for args: "[]":  

Called method "'_trackEvent','Store_Outbound','Link_Click'" threw exception.TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

whereas it should give something like this:

```
_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Store_Outbound,Link_Click]":
```

guess it's the way I build the parameters with the variables that's causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the values wrong. This is effectively what you are doing:

`_gaq.push(["a,b,c"]);`

That is an array with a single element.

This is what it should look like:

`_gaq.push(["a","b","c"]);`

This is an array with multiple elements.

So basically you need to do

```
params = [t1,t2,t3];
_gaq.push(params);
```

or just put them directly in:

```
_gaq.push([t1,t2,t3]);
```